# Raid 1 on two partitions: is this a good thing to do?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, software-raid, raid1

So, I have a 2TB HDD (`sda`) and a 500GB one (`sdb`). I created a partition on `sdb` occupying the entire device (`sdb1`), noted how large it is, and then I created a partition on `sda` the same size (`sda1`).

Then, I created a RAID1 array between the two partitions: `mdadm --create /dev/md/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1`.

What I want to achieve is having a partition on `sda` (`sda1`) that's mirrored to `sdb`. I am new with RAID. Is the way I've done things good? Is there any better way? I'd be glad to hear some suggestions

Comment: Why do you want to mirror ? because sdb is much older than the other one and you want to preserve its content in any case at any time ? or/and because you run applications highly demanding in terms of read operations on sdb1 ?  How do you intend to use the remaining 1,5 TB on sda ? Any forecast regarding concurrent usage (the remaining 1,5TB / sda1) ? You should tell much more !

Comment: The reason I want to mirror is to have a part of the large hard drive (`sda`) that is always backed up, because I already had an incident recently. I'm using two drives that are different because I want to work with what I have on hand already, and because I don't plan on buying hard drives any time soon. On the remaining 1,5TB I'll just have a normal partition where I'll keep less important stuff, so that is still going to be used.

Comment: RAID isn’t a backup tool, as far as data resilience goes it’s only useful to maintain system availability. If you want a backup you’d be better off setting up regular backups to your 500G drive (and keeping it offline when you’re not running backups).

Comment: Then... any suggestions for that? I knew that RAID1 was the most overkill way to 'backup' but I didn't think much for anything else

Comment: It's completely fine to use partitions for mdadm. RAID not a backup is another matter - up to you to decide what is suitable for your use case. If you don't want to lose data, you still need a backup - but yesterday's backup might do you no good either if you still lost today's data. So it might make sense to have both the mirror and the backup.

Comment: There are many solutions for taking and managing backups, which is the right on for you might depend on circumstances you haven't mentioned. Personally I used to use a wrapper around `rsync --link-dest` that I had written myself, now I often use borgbackup. (And that is in addition to having a RAID setup, because RAID is not backup)

Comment: @frostschutz I would do that, but I don't have that many drives in order to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAID1 is about mirroring. It doesn't matter whether you mirror a partition or a disk.

Given your description it sounds like you've addressed the requirement correctly: you have a 500GB partition on `/dev/sdb1` that has been equalled by a partition of 500GB on your 2TB disk, and you've created a RAID1 mirror across them both.

You can use `cat /proc/mdstat` to see the configuration (and mirroring state, if it's still in progress).

Remember though, that RAID is not a backup - if you accidentally delete (or otherwise break) a file then it will be deleted (or broken) on both halves of the mirror. You *might* have been better off leaving the two halves as separate partitions and then using the older 500GB disk as a periodic backup of the newer partition. (`rsnapshot` on top of `rsync` is one of my preferred solutions, for example, and the proprietary [Veeam Agent for Linux](https://www.veeam.com/linux-backup-free.html?ad=downloads) is another.) But it does very much depend on the situation and your particular requirements.

Comment: I think I'll take a look at rsnapshot, it looks quite interesting

Answer (score 3):

> Raid 1 on two partitions: is this a good thing to do?

**R** standing for *Redundancy*, it will depend on the reason why you want that redundancy.

**In general at first: system's availability** :
The very first reason for wanting redundancy is in a context of fault-tolerance : Guarantee your system will remain fully functional (to the possible expense of reduced performances) even in case of some hardware failure.
Why would you want RAID-1 ? In order for your system to stay fully functional in case one of your two drives stops functioning.

**Performance of read operations** (In the particular case of RAID-1)
If your workload mainly consists in tasks heavily random-reading concurrently on disk, you might want to share the i/o load on two different controllers and efficiently increase the throughput.

All this of course does not come for free. At least whatever write operation will be (much) dearer.

---

Because of that cost (and misc. other drawbacks), **you do not want RAID-1 as a solution for only preserving data**.

For the sole sake of preserving data on some reputed filesystem (the ext family, zfs, ufs…), I personally ensure most secure mount options (generally default) are selected then use [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for backing up.
rsync can of course be launched from cron, run daemonized, and, what I prefer in any case : scheduled SCHED_BATCH (in order to operate only when your system has just nothing else to achieve)
In any case, this will do the job in a far cheaper & secure way than whatever RAID config.